# Create iOS custom framework using storyboard and viewcontroller

Tags: ios, frameworks

I would like to create a framework that contains a custom storyboard and custom ViewControllers (containing a TableView). The app using this framework will be to segue into the custom ViewController like any other ViewController.

My question is first is this possible and if so how to implement this. Ive found a few tutorials how to include controller logic in a framework but none on how to include a storyboard.

Any tutorials or reference material would be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference a storyboard within your framework.  You need to reference your framework's bundle specifically to get at the storyboard.

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.custom.framework.bundle.id")
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NameOfStoryboard", bundle: bundle)
```

If the view/views are not complex in your storyboard, consider creating xib and a corresponding UIView file.

Comment: Great that worked! Working onto the next step I have a follow up.

Using the storyboard I next instantiate a VC and then navigate to it:
`let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SessionViewController")
 self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

The storyboard will use multiple VCs embedded in a Navigation VC. The app using the framework will also have its own Navigation VC. Is it possible to use both? Looks like there could be a conflict in this situation.

Comment: It's definitely possible to use both, although I can see it getting hard to manage your view hierarchy from the app side.  Try to keep the logic where it makes most sense.  If you're interacting with both the framework resources and the app resources, it makes you wonder why they were separated in the first place.